# RavenDB with WPF/Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, architecture, ravendb, caliburn.micro

It seems the reference implementation for web apps is RacoonBlog, but I've had trouble finding examples of working with WPF/SL. The fundamental difference is the lifetime of ViewModels and the coarseness of data changes - they generally occur per-property rather than per-object. The few examples I have seen have used the Repository pattern which i'm keen to avoid.

Is there a recommended practice for such things? Should I be making a base VM with a reference to the DocumentStore and saving everything there (triggered by PropertyChanged events)?

Answer (score 1):

First consider if you should talk directly to the database or not from your client.  In many cases, regardless of the database technology, you will want to have the client speak to an intermediary, such services layer (WebAPI, ServiceStack, WCF, or otherwise).

Then, if you decide you really do want to talk directly to the database, the specifics are the same as in other code.

1. Only one instance of DocumentStore should exist at runtime.
2. You should open and close a new DocumentSession per activity of the user.

If your UI is course-grained, then you may be storing/updating an entire entity in the session.  If your UI is fine-grained (ex: Task-based UI), then you will be doing less in each session and you will have more of them.

The other option is to use raven's [Patching API](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates) to perform partial updates, however it's usually not required or desired.  You lose transactions and concurrency exceptions just to gain less wire traffic.

You should think about how you want to handle concurrency issues.  [Optimistic Concurrency](http://ravendb.net/kb/16/using-optimistic-concurrency-in-real-world-scenarios) is probably a good idea, but be sure to handle the exceptions with retry logic.

You will need to use [async session operations](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/working-asynchronously) when coming from SL, and probably a good idea for WPF also.